# ElasticSearch - Optional arguments for FILTER?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make an optional choice for `FILTER`, so if I input a specific term, the result will filter by it, otherwise match everything.

Here is my trial code :

```
 "filter" : { 
    "bool" : {
        "should" : [  
            { "terms" : { "item.brand" : [ "{{brand}}"] }} ,
            {"match_all":{}}
        ]
    }
```

However, when I run:

```
{
        "id": "bipbip002",
        "params": {
            "query_all": "Table"
            "brand":""
        }
}
```

I got this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filter].",
                "line": 1,
                "col": 302
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filter].",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 302
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Currently, working on version 7el

MAPPING INFO

```
          "item": {
                "properties": {
                    "brand": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }

"name": {
                            "properties": {
                                "en": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
```

Logic behind:
Search name of Item, if users click on the filter button, send an API to an existing template which the filter argument is optional

Comment: can you provide your index-mapping, sample and expected results so that we can provide you the query which might solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional queries(aka if...else) are not supported directly in elasticsearch DSL, you need to do this conditional logic in your app-server which is firing the ES queries.

Please refer to the [conditional clause in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-template.html#search-template-conditional-clauses) for more info.

Comment: The link is very useful, but i don get what is the `{{#line_no}}` ,

Comment: @ChauLoi, in the offical example they took `line_no` fields which is of type int, and on this field they are making `range_query` so `line_no` is nothing but the field in example index

Comment: @ChauLoi please go through little up in the same link and you will get the complete context

Comment: just add the Mapping, hope u can provide an example for me

Comment: @ChauLoi as mentioned in the docs it doesn't support the JSON format :(, and I am not familiar with string syntax, I can try but this would take a lot of my time, hope somebody else familer in the community can provide the exact answer you are looking for